# How to use multiple callback / subscribe / wait until a method finish in angular 13?

Tags: angular, typescript, callback

I tried a lot of mechanism to implement a callback but I don't know it doesn't work in angular. I used these methods: https://sebhastian.com/javascript-wait-for-function-to-finish/ and tried a suscribe/observable but doesn't work.

In basic, I've three methods:

```
    search() {
       this.postdata();
       this.endmessage();
    }

    endmessage() {
     console.log("finally!");
    }

   postdata() {
      //Several calls to an API like this one:

this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'dictionary/getrae', body, { headers: headers, responseType: 'text', withCredentials: true }).subscribe(result => {
  this.resultado = result;
}, error => console.error(error));


this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'dictionary/getrae2', body, { headers: headers, responseType: 'text', withCredentials: true }).subscribe(result => {
  this.resultado2 = result;
}, error => console.error(error));

   }
```

As said, I tried with `postdata(callback)` but doesn't work. I tried with subscribe but I get `"property suscribe does not exist on type void"`, `"number"` or `whatever`

I'm working on NET 6.0 and Angular 13 with typescript.

Comment: So are you looking to have `endmessage()` method get called after `postdata()`?

Comment: @Mohamed.Karkotly yes exactly, after all "post" are done. Some posts finishes before others, I don't care the order, but I need do an action after everyone is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either wrap all your async code with a `Promise` and return it, and afterwards you can `.then()` that `Promise` or you would have to place your callback methods within the `.subscribe()` block, but those both are bad things to do.

I would recommend the following method as it's of Angular's best practices.

You first need to create a service containing 2 methods, one is for the first `POST` call and second method is for the second one like this:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataService {
  // Declare baseUrl here
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  postdata1(body: any): Observable<any> {
    // Recieve body as a parameter
    // Declare headers here if they were special to this request in a global scope if nt
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'dictionary/getrae', body, {
      headers: headers,
      responseType: 'text',
      withCredentials: true,
    });
  }

  postdata2(body: any): Observable<any> {
    // Declare headers here if they were special to this request in a global scope if nt
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'dictionary/getrae', body, {
      headers: headers,
      responseType: 'text',
      withCredentials: true,
    });
  }
}
```

Note that both methods are returning an `Observable<any>`.

Now since you need to make both `POST` requests together, you will have to use **RxJS** `forkJoin` operator like the following:

In the same component you shared, use DI design pattern to inject your service

```
constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}
```

Create a method that performs both calls

```
getData1AndData2() {
  let data1$ = this.dataService.postdata1(YOUR_BODY_Object_1);
  let data2$ = tthis.dataService.postdata1(YOUR_BODY_Object_2);
  return forkJoin([data1$, data2$]).subscribe((responses) => {
    this.response1 = responses[0];
    this.response2 = responses[1];
    this.endmessage(); // Here's where your method need to get called
  });
}
```

Here's the Marble Diagram for how `forkJoin` works.
[image: forkJoin Marble Diagram]

For more information about `forkJoin` operator, check out the documentation [here](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin).

Comment: THANKS a lot for the explanation and the time you invest here. I had to study this and learn it.

Comment: Sorry for disturb you. This is not in my original question. When a post is completed, I have a `this.message = "step 1 completed"` . How can I do this after moved to the service? (I'm working with the service right now)

Comment: Refer to `getData1AndData2()` method, within the `.subscribe` block, you can find the method `this.endmessage();` that contains your `log` call, or the `this.message` assignment you're doing now.

Comment: I made this question if you have a little time! Thanks!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73041884/how-to-update-the-ui-after-every-observable-finish-in-forkjoin-on-angular